# Save arrayList Hashmap in database

Tags: android

How to save ArrayList< HashMap< String, String>> in database?

Getting NULL values in the database

I tried this method: [Saving records into the database from the hashmap in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666722/saving-records-into-the-database-from-the-hashmap-in-android)
but didn't help

```
public void addQuote(Quote q, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> put_q_list)
{

  try{
    myDataBase=this.getWritableDatabase();
   ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

  values.put("q_customer_name", q.getCustomer_name());
  values.put("q_customer_email", q.getCustomer_email());
  values.put("q_b_street", q.getBilling_street());
  values.put("q_b_city", q.getBilling_city());
  values.put("q_b_state", q.getBilling_state());
  values.put("q_b_zipcode", q.getBilling_zipcode());
  values.put("q_b_country", q.getBilling_country());
  values.put("q_s_street", q.getShipping_street());
  values.put("q_s_city", q.getShipping_city());
  values.put("q_s_state", q.getShipping_state());
  values.put("q_s_zipcode", q.getShipping_zipcode());
  values.put("q_s_country", q.getShipping_country());
  values.put("q_day", q.getDay());
  values.put("q_month", q.getMonth());
  values.put("q_year", q.getYear());
  values.put("q_total", q.getTotal());
  values.put("q_discount", q.getTotal_discount());

  myDataBase.insert("quote",null,values);

  }catch(Exception e)
  {
      Log.e("bderror",e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  String selectQuery = "SELECT quote_id FROM quote WHERE q_customer_email=?";
  Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {q.getCustomer_email()});
  int i=0;
  while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
      i=cursor.getInt(0);
    }
  cursor.close();
  myDataBase.beginTransaction();
  for (int j = 0; j < put_q_list.size(); j++) {
       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
       map = put_q_list.get(j);

       //Each value by using this method
       String item_code = map.get("item_code_final");

       ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
       cv.put("quote_id", i);
       cv.put("q_item_code", item_code);
       myDataBase.insert("q_item", null, cv);
    }
  myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();
  myDataBase.endTransaction();
  myDataBase.close();
}
```

Only the value of "i" is being inserted!!! not the item code
Please help!!!

Comment: what is your code that you used??

Comment: try now, I think your `i` variable was the issue\

Comment: not that, the value of "i" is inserted
but rest of the fields are null in the database

Comment: debug and observe the result of this line `String item_code = map.get("item_code_final");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. It should work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mapList.size(); i++) {
   HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
   map = mapList.get(i);

  ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
   cv.put("quote_id", i);
   cv.put("q_item_code", map.get("item_code_final"));
   cv.put("q_item_desc", map.get("desc_final"));
   cv.put("q_item_price", map.get("item_price_final"));
   cv.put("q_item_qty", map.get("item_qty_final"));
   cv.put("q_item_tax", map.get("item_tax_final"));
   cv.put("q_item_discount", map.get("item_discount_final")); 
   db.insert("tablename", null, cv);
}
db.close();
```

Comment: Still the values are null

Comment: @user3319217 do on thing instead of using map.get("..."); directly to database, First put it in a string Log.i on that variable so you know if you are getting the value or not. Then insert it. Its more like knowing where the error exactly is

Answer (score 0):

You should first declare an Database instance to deal with and begin the transactions. as following

```
SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getDatabase();
db.beginTransaction();
```

Then perform the loop

```
for(HashMap<String, String> map : mylist){
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(FILE_NAME, map.get(FILE_NAME));
cv.put(DESC, map.get(DESC));
cv.put(UPLOADED_BY, map.get(DATE_UPLOADED));
cv.put(ACTION, map.get(FILE_NAME));
cv.put(ID, map.get(ID));
cv.put(FILE_URI, map.get(FILE_URI));
db.insert("tablename", null, cv);
}
```

Then close the `cursor`

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

That was clear in your link in the accepted answer

Comment: I had put that code
am not getting an error but getting null values in database